# Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from Cursor Window when quering from uri in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I know there is a lot similiar question, and I have read most of them and they relate to something else. 
I have this error :

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=android:fragment:1, request=2, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.google.android.gallery3d.provider/picasa/item/5953655552200168930 flg=0x1 }} to activity {std.app/std.app.activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```

The problem is it works on some devices, and on some not. For example it works on SGS2, but not on Nexus 7. 
More logs :

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
    at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
    at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:434)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
    at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:114)
    at std.app.util.PhotoUtils.getRealPathFromURI(PhotoUtils.java:124)
    at std.app.fragments.DayFragment.onActivityResult(DayFragment.java:167)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5427)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3347)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3394)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and here is the code which makes error :

```
    public static String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentURI) {
    String result;
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) {
        result = contentURI.getPath();
    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        result = cursor.getString(idx); // this line
        cursor.close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Is the `MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA` different in different versions? How to fix this?

EDIT : 
I have noticed that this is not the problem of version, but the problem of source. This error shows only when I pick a picture from Picassa folders.

Comment: use DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cursor) to see wha'ts inside

Comment: here it is : user_account=blabla@gmail.com
picasa_id=6025489200566456194
_display_name=IMG_5412.jpg
_size=560910
mime_type=image/jpeg
datetaken=1402833202000
latitude=null
longitude=null
orientation=0

Comment: and you want to get DATA http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns.html#DATA which is "_data" and there is no such column in your Cursor

Comment: You are right, it seems I cannot get pictures from Picassa folder, I can only do that with SD. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: no, i have no idea...

Comment: Guess it would be too complicated, thanks for answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that's because cloud synced Photos (a.k.a. Picassa folder) do not have a physical address in the SD card or internal memory, it is not a physical file on the device. The column `MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA` is for physical files on the device.

The way to "grab" this image is to open an Stream and copy the image over to a folder you control (a temporary folder in your app, maybe from `Context.getCacheDir()` method).

```
     InputStream is = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
     OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(tempFile));
```

and then proceeded with copying from the input to the output and close the streams at the end.
Remember that this process is a network operation, that means you should never do it from the UI thread.

If you're using an image library like `Picasso` (which you should always use) you can just let it do all the work for you and just pass the `Uri` directly to it like this `Picasso.with(context).load(uri).into(target);` this target can either be an `ImageView` or any object that `implements Target`